# Qual a diferença entre Attach, setar EntityState para Modified e CurrentValues.SetValues?

Tags: entity-framework

Qual a diferença entre os métodos para atualizar um registro por meio do EntityFramework?

1. **Attach**:

   ```
   dbContext.Pessoas.Attach(model);
   ```
2. Setar o **`State`** de uma entrada para **`EntityState.Modified`**:

   ```
   dbContext.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
   ```
3. E por meio da mudança dos valores de uma entrada por **`CurrentValues.SetValues`**:

   ```
   dbContext.Entry(entry).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Attach

Anexa um registro ao contexto. É um comportamento otimista: o Entity Framework espera que o registro exista e apenas observa outros registros que façam uso deste registro anexado. Qualquer modificação feita no registro anexado não é repassada ao banco de dados.

Fonte: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

## `State = EntityState.Modified`

Indica ao Entity Framework que o objeto (portanto, o registro) foi modificado e deve ser persistido em banco ao invocar o método `SaveChanges`.

A priori, registros carregados por seleção não são marcados para serem persistidos. O programador deve fazer isso manualmente. É desta forma para evitar que o `SaveChanges` faça alguma alteração indevida em banco em entidades que não devem ser modificadas.

## `CurrentValues.SetValues`

Altera diretamente os valores e marca a entrada do objeto como modificada. Uma chamada ao `SaveChanges` fará uma atualização dos valores atualizados por `SetValues`.

[Veja mais sobre `CurrentValues` aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696217(v=vs.113).aspx).

[Veja mais sobre o `SetValues` e outros métodos e propriedades de `CurrentValues` aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyvalues(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra resposta para essa pergunta é baseada quase que completamente em uma outra **[pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336248/entity-framework-5-updating-a-record)** que encontrei no **SOen**.

O autor da pergunta estava explorando algumas formas de atualizar um registro e entre elas ele listou algumas:

### Método 1 - Carregar o registro original, alterar cada propriedade e então salvar.

```
var original = db.Users.Find(updatedUser.UserId);

if (original != null)
{
    original.BusinessEntityId = updatedUser.BusinessEntityId;
    original.Email = updatedUser.Email;
    original.EmployeeId = updatedUser.EmployeeId;
    original.Forename = updatedUser.Forename;
    original.Surname = updatedUser.Surname;
    original.Telephone = updatedUser.Telephone;
    original.Title = updatedUser.Title;
    original.Fax = updatedUser.Fax;
    original.ASPNetUserId = updatedUser.ASPNetUserId;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**As vangatens são** as de poder utilizar tranquilamente uma ***ViewModel***, permitindo assim que você tenha uma classe sem todas as propriedades da classe de domínio e então facilitar a projeção da View. Com isso, você precisa setar as propriedades que você vai salvar, não precisando assim ter todas os campos da classe de domínio na view e poder salvar a alteração de apenas os campos que você alterou.

Já as **desvantagens** estão em: 
Ter duas requisições ao banco de dados. Uma para recuperar o registro original (registro que está no banco de dados com os dados atuais) e a requisição para persistir os dados no banco de dados (`db.SaveChanges()`).

### Método 2 - carregar o registro original e fazer o uso de `db.Entry(T)CurrentValues.SetValues();`.

```
var original = db.Users.Find(updatedUser.UserId);

if (original != null)
{
    db.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedUser);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Aqui, as **vantagens** estão em setar as propriedades modificadas com apenas duas linhas de comando. 
Somente as propriedades alteradas serão enviadas para o banco de dados.

As **desvantagens** ficam por conta da sua view necessitar ter todas as propriedades (aqui, `**updateUser**` não é uma viewModel, mas sim uma classe do próprio )domínio 
Também são feitas duas requisições ao banco de dados. Uma para obter o registro original e outra pra salvar o registro.